# Why ViewTreeObserver > OnScrollChangedListener not called on Android 2.x if it set in onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I discovered that `OnScrollChangedListener` on Android 2.x won't be ever fired if it was added before the first time layout draw. For example, when you add a scroll listener in methods like `onCreate`/`onResume`/`onAttachedToWindow`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View myView = findViewById(R.id.MyView);

        System.out.println(myView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()); // true

        myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                // will never fire
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**So, anybody knows the reason of this problem?**

---

**PS:** Seems like the problem sometime happens on API<=15 (Android 4.0.3)

Comment: Thanks alot for updating your question. I would prefer answering your own question and then accepting it. It would increase readability.

Comment: @Pradeep, done! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it seems like a bug. And here is a simple workaround:

To make `OnScrollChangedListener` work on old devices (apparently API<=15), you should add it either in `onWindowFocusChanged(true)`, or after the layout is measured (use `GlobalLayoutListener`).

And don't to forget to create a flag like `isScrollListenerAdded` to avoid repeated listener attaching.

Something like this:

```
myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (!isScrollListenerAdded) {
            isScrollListenerAdded = true;
            // add OnScrollChangedListener here
        }
    }
});
```

Details are available in this [blog post about OnScrollChangedListener](http://azagroup.ru/android-2-viewtreeobserver-onscrollchangedlistener-not-called/) (Rus; Kotlin)